# MeteorJS JSON Parsing

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Simple JSON parsing is not working for me I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing.

I have an iron-router, server rout setup to receive an HTTP webhook

```
this.route('inboundLink', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '/inbound-link',
        action: function() {
            var request = this.request;
            var response = this.response;

            console.log(this.request.body.mandrill_events);
            var json = JSON.parse(this.request.body.mandrill_events);

            console.log(json);
            console.log(json["event"]);
            console.log(json.event);
            console.log(json.email);
        }
    });
```

But JSON event, JSON email is always returning undefined

Here is the JSON file from the first console.log this.request.body.mandrill_events

```
[
    {
        "event": "inbound",
        "msg": {
            "dkim": {
                "signed": true,
                "valid": true
            },
            "email": "link@add.linklyapp.com",
            "from_email": "example.sender@mandrillapp.com",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\"",
                "Date": "Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000",
                "Dkim-Signature": [
                    "v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; h=From:Sender:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; bh=d60x72jf42gLILD7IiqBL0OBb40=; b=iJd7eBugdIjzqW84UZ2xynlg1SojANJR6xfz0JDD44h78EpbqJiYVcMIfRG7mkrn741Bd5YaMR6p 9j41OA9A5am+8BE1Ng2kLRGwou5hRInn+xXBAQm2NUt5FkoXSpvm4gC4gQSOxPbQcuzlLha9JqxJ 8ZZ89/20txUrRq9cYxk=",
                    "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=c.mandrillapp.com; i=@c.mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1368214100; h=From : Sender : Subject : List-Unsubscribe : To : Message-Id : Date : MIME-Version : Content-Type : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : List-Unsubscribe; bh=y5Vz+RDcKZmWzRc9s0xUJR6k4APvBNktBqy1EhSWM8o=; b=PLAUIuw8zk8kG5tPkmcnSanElxt6I5lp5t32nSvzVQE7R8u0AmIEjeIDZEt31+Q9PWt+nY sHHRsXUQ9SZpndT9Bk++/SmyA2ntU/2AKuqDpPkMZiTqxmGF80Wz4JJgx2aCEB1LeLVmFFwB 5Nr/LBSlsBlRcjT9QiWw0/iRvCn74="
                ],
                "Domainkey-Signature": "a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; b=X6qudHd4oOJvVQZcoAEUCJgB875SwzEO5UKf6NvpfqyCVjdaO79WdDulLlfNVELeuoK2m6alt2yw 5Qhp4TW5NegyFf6Ogr/Hy0Lt411r/0lRf0nyaVkqMM/9g13B6D9CS092v70wshX8+qdyxK8fADw8 kEelbCK2cEl0AGIeAeo=;",
                "From": "<example.sender@mandrillapp.com>",
                "List-Unsubscribe": "<mailto:unsubscribe-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mailin1.us2.mcsv.net?subject=unsub>",
                "Message-Id": "<999.20130510192820.aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>",
                "Mime-Version": "1.0",
                "Received": [
                    "from mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com (mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com [205.201.136.115]) by mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id AAAAAAAAAAA for <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:21 +0000 (UTC)",
                    "from localhost (127.0.0.1) by mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com id hhl55a14i282 for <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>)"
                ],
                "Sender": "<example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>",
                "Subject": "This is an example webhook message",
                "To": "<link@add.linklyapp.com>",
                "X-Report-Abuse": "Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com"
            },
            "html": "<p>This is an example inbound message.</p><img src=\"http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=999&id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&tags=_all,_sendexample.sender@mandrillapp.com\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\">\n",
            "raw_msg": "Received: from mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com (mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com [205.201.136.115])\n\tby mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id AAAAAAAAAAA\n\tfor <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000 (UTC)\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;\n h=From:Sender:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;\n bh=d60x72jf42gLILD7IiqBL0OBb40=;\n b=iJd7eBugdIjzqW84UZ2xynlg1SojANJR6xfz0JDD44h78EpbqJiYVcMIfRG7mkrn741Bd5YaMR6p\n 9j41OA9A5am+8BE1Ng2kLRGwou5hRInn+xXBAQm2NUt5FkoXSpvm4gC4gQSOxPbQcuzlLha9JqxJ\n 8ZZ89/20txUrRq9cYxk=\nDomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;\n b=X6qudHd4oOJvVQZcoAEUCJgB875SwzEO5UKf6NvpfqyCVjdaO79WdDulLlfNVELeuoK2m6alt2yw\n 5Qhp4TW5NegyFf6Ogr/Hy0Lt411r/0lRf0nyaVkqMM/9g13B6D9CS092v70wshX8+qdyxK8fADw8\n kEelbCK2cEl0AGIeAeo=;\nReceived: from localhost (127.0.0.1) by mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com id hhl55a14i282 for <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>)\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=c.mandrillapp.com; \n i=@c.mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1368214100; h=From : \n Sender : Subject : List-Unsubscribe : To : Message-Id : Date : \n MIME-Version : Content-Type : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : \n List-Unsubscribe; bh=y5Vz+RDcKZmWzRc9s0xUJR6k4APvBNktBqy1EhSWM8o=; \n b=PLAUIuw8zk8kG5tPkmcnSanElxt6I5lp5t32nSvzVQE7R8u0AmIEjeIDZEt31+Q9PWt+nY\n sHHRsXUQ9SZpndT9Bk++/SmyA2ntU/2AKuqDpPkMZiTqxmGF80Wz4JJgx2aCEB1LeLVmFFwB\n 5Nr/LBSlsBlRcjT9QiWw0/iRvCn74=\nFrom: <example.sender@mandrillapp.com>\nSender: <example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>\nSubject: This is an example webhook message\nList-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mailin1.us2.mcsv.net?subject=unsub>\nTo: <link@add.linklyapp.com>\nX-Report-Abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com\nX-Mandrill-User: md_999\nMessage-Id: <999.20130510192820.aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>\nDate: Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\"\n\n--_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\nThis is an example inbound message.\n--_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n<p>This is an example inbound message.</p><img src=\"http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=999&id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&tags=_all,_sendexample.sender@mandrillapp.com\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\">\n--_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw--",
            "sender": null,
            "spam_report": {
                "matched_rules": [
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": null,
                        "name": null,
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "in iadb.isipp.com]",
                        "name": "listed",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: Participates in the IADB system",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_LISTED",
                        "score": -0.4
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: ISIPP IADB lists as vouched-for sender",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_VOUCHED",
                        "score": -2.2
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender publishes SPF record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_SPF",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender publishes Sender ID record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_SENDERID",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender publishes Domain Keys record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_DK",
                        "score": -0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender has reverse DNS record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_RDNS",
                        "score": -0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "SPF: HELO matches SPF record",
                        "name": "SPF_HELO_PASS",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "BODY: HTML included in message",
                        "name": "HTML_MESSAGE",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "BODY: HTML: images with 0-400 bytes of words",
                        "name": "HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_04",
                        "score": 0.3
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid",
                        "name": "DKIM_SIGNED",
                        "score": 0.1
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature",
                        "name": "DKIM_VALID",
                        "score": -0.1
                    }
                ],
                "score": -2.6
            },
            "spf": {
                "detail": "sender SPF authorized",
                "result": "pass"
            },
            "subject": "This is an example webhook message",
            "tags": [],
            "template": null,
            "text": "This is an example inbound message.\n",
            "text_flowed": false,
            "to": [
                [
                    "link@add.linklyapp.com",
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        "ts": 1368214102
    },
    {
        "event": "inbound",
        "msg": {
            "dkim": {
                "signed": true,
                "valid": true
            },
            "email": "link@add.linklyapp.com",
            "from_email": "example.sender@mandrillapp.com",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\"",
                "Date": "Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000",
                "Dkim-Signature": [
                    "v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; h=From:Sender:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; bh=d60x72jf42gLILD7IiqBL0OBb40=; b=iJd7eBugdIjzqW84UZ2xynlg1SojANJR6xfz0JDD44h78EpbqJiYVcMIfRG7mkrn741Bd5YaMR6p 9j41OA9A5am+8BE1Ng2kLRGwou5hRInn+xXBAQm2NUt5FkoXSpvm4gC4gQSOxPbQcuzlLha9JqxJ 8ZZ89/20txUrRq9cYxk=",
                    "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=c.mandrillapp.com; i=@c.mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1368214100; h=From : Sender : Subject : List-Unsubscribe : To : Message-Id : Date : MIME-Version : Content-Type : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : List-Unsubscribe; bh=y5Vz+RDcKZmWzRc9s0xUJR6k4APvBNktBqy1EhSWM8o=; b=PLAUIuw8zk8kG5tPkmcnSanElxt6I5lp5t32nSvzVQE7R8u0AmIEjeIDZEt31+Q9PWt+nY sHHRsXUQ9SZpndT9Bk++/SmyA2ntU/2AKuqDpPkMZiTqxmGF80Wz4JJgx2aCEB1LeLVmFFwB 5Nr/LBSlsBlRcjT9QiWw0/iRvCn74="
                ],
                "Domainkey-Signature": "a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; b=X6qudHd4oOJvVQZcoAEUCJgB875SwzEO5UKf6NvpfqyCVjdaO79WdDulLlfNVELeuoK2m6alt2yw 5Qhp4TW5NegyFf6Ogr/Hy0Lt411r/0lRf0nyaVkqMM/9g13B6D9CS092v70wshX8+qdyxK8fADw8 kEelbCK2cEl0AGIeAeo=;",
                "From": "<example.sender@mandrillapp.com>",
                "List-Unsubscribe": "<mailto:unsubscribe-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mailin1.us2.mcsv.net?subject=unsub>",
                "Message-Id": "<999.20130510192820.aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>",
                "Mime-Version": "1.0",
                "Received": [
                    "from mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com (mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com [205.201.136.115]) by mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id AAAAAAAAAAA for <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:21 +0000 (UTC)",
                    "from localhost (127.0.0.1) by mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com id hhl55a14i282 for <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>)"
                ],
                "Sender": "<example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>",
                "Subject": "This is an example webhook message",
                "To": "<link@add.linklyapp.com>",
                "X-Report-Abuse": "Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com"
            },
            "html": "<p>This is an example inbound message.</p><img src=\"http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=999&id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&tags=_all,_sendexample.sender@mandrillapp.com\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\">\n",
            "raw_msg": "Received: from mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com (mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com [205.201.136.115])\n\tby mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id AAAAAAAAAAA\n\tfor <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000 (UTC)\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;\n h=From:Sender:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;\n bh=d60x72jf42gLILD7IiqBL0OBb40=;\n b=iJd7eBugdIjzqW84UZ2xynlg1SojANJR6xfz0JDD44h78EpbqJiYVcMIfRG7mkrn741Bd5YaMR6p\n 9j41OA9A5am+8BE1Ng2kLRGwou5hRInn+xXBAQm2NUt5FkoXSpvm4gC4gQSOxPbQcuzlLha9JqxJ\n 8ZZ89/20txUrRq9cYxk=\nDomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;\n b=X6qudHd4oOJvVQZcoAEUCJgB875SwzEO5UKf6NvpfqyCVjdaO79WdDulLlfNVELeuoK2m6alt2yw\n 5Qhp4TW5NegyFf6Ogr/Hy0Lt411r/0lRf0nyaVkqMM/9g13B6D9CS092v70wshX8+qdyxK8fADw8\n kEelbCK2cEl0AGIeAeo=;\nReceived: from localhost (127.0.0.1) by mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com id hhl55a14i282 for <link@add.linklyapp.com>; Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>)\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=c.mandrillapp.com; \n i=@c.mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1368214100; h=From : \n Sender : Subject : List-Unsubscribe : To : Message-Id : Date : \n MIME-Version : Content-Type : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : \n List-Unsubscribe; bh=y5Vz+RDcKZmWzRc9s0xUJR6k4APvBNktBqy1EhSWM8o=; \n b=PLAUIuw8zk8kG5tPkmcnSanElxt6I5lp5t32nSvzVQE7R8u0AmIEjeIDZEt31+Q9PWt+nY\n sHHRsXUQ9SZpndT9Bk++/SmyA2ntU/2AKuqDpPkMZiTqxmGF80Wz4JJgx2aCEB1LeLVmFFwB\n 5Nr/LBSlsBlRcjT9QiWw0/iRvCn74=\nFrom: <example.sender@mandrillapp.com>\nSender: <example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>\nSubject: This is an example webhook message\nList-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe-md_999.aaaaaaaa.v1-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@mailin1.us2.mcsv.net?subject=unsub>\nTo: <link@add.linklyapp.com>\nX-Report-Abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com\nX-Mandrill-User: md_999\nMessage-Id: <999.20130510192820.aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.aaaaaaaa@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com>\nDate: Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\"\n\n--_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\nThis is an example inbound message.\n--_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n<p>This is an example inbound message.</p><img src=\"http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=999&id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&tags=_all,_sendexample.sender@mandrillapp.com\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\">\n--_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw--",
            "sender": null,
            "spam_report": {
                "matched_rules": [
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": null,
                        "name": null,
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "in iadb.isipp.com]",
                        "name": "listed",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: Participates in the IADB system",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_LISTED",
                        "score": -0.4
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: ISIPP IADB lists as vouched-for sender",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_VOUCHED",
                        "score": -2.2
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender publishes SPF record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_SPF",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender publishes Sender ID record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_SENDERID",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender publishes Domain Keys record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_DK",
                        "score": -0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "RBL: IADB: Sender has reverse DNS record",
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_IADB_RDNS",
                        "score": -0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "SPF: HELO matches SPF record",
                        "name": "SPF_HELO_PASS",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "BODY: HTML included in message",
                        "name": "HTML_MESSAGE",
                        "score": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "BODY: HTML: images with 0-400 bytes of words",
                        "name": "HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_04",
                        "score": 0.3
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid",
                        "name": "DKIM_SIGNED",
                        "score": 0.1
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature",
                        "name": "DKIM_VALID",
                        "score": -0.1
                    }
                ],
                "score": -2.6
            },
            "spf": {
                "detail": "sender SPF authorized",
                "result": "pass"
            },
            "subject": "This is an example webhook message",
            "tags": [],
            "template": null,
            "text": "This is an example inbound message.\n",
            "text_flowed": false,
            "to": [
                [
                    "link@add.linklyapp.com",
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        "ts": 1368214102
    }
]
```

Comment: it seems already parsed, i.e. it seems you don't need to call JSON.parse again something is already a JS object.

Comment: It seems the returned JSON message is an array, what about `json[0].event` ?

Comment: I tried with and without the JSON.parse

Comment: Yea that worked not sure why I missed that it was an array